# openmp: barrier synchronization not working within loop with if condition

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I have the following code:

```
#pragma omp parallel shared(a,n) private(i,j,k,x,pid,rows,mymin,mymax)
{
    //  nprocs=1;
#ifdef _OPENMP
    nprocs=omp_get_num_threads();
#endif

#ifdef _OPENMP
    pid=omp_get_thread_num();
#endif

    rows=n/nprocs;
    mymin=pid * rows;
    mymax=mymin + rows - 1;

    for(k=0;k<n;k++){
        if(k>=mymin && k<=mymax){
#pragma omp for schedule(static,rows)
            for(x=k+1;x<n;x++){
                a[k][x]= a[k][x]/a[k][k];
            }
#pragma omp barrier
        }
    }
}
```

Here I am selecting which thread will update which row of matrix based on the if condition. For eg, if there are two threads, thread 1 will update first two rows of matrix 'a' and thread 2 will update the other two.

And after I selected that, I divide the iterations on the columns of that row by paralleling the inner loop among thread 1 and two( where I start     `for(x=k+1,x<n;x++)`). I am also putting a barrier after the inner for loop so that after every column value of single row is updated, its synchronized.

But the problem is I am not getting proper synchronized values. In the final matrix, some values updated by thread 0 are shown in some rows and some by other thread but not all.

Answer (score 1):

Using `omp barrier` here is useless since there is an implicit barrier at the end of a `omp for` construct unless a `nowait` clause is specified.

On the other hand, you don't need to manually specify how to decompose the work to threads, and the way you decompose is not correct.

What you are trying to do in fact can be written as follows.

```
#pragma omp parallel for shared(a,n) private(k,x)
for(k=0;k<n;k++){
    for(x=k+1;x<n;x++){
        a[k][x]= a[k][x]/a[k][k];
    }
}
```

Since the work load is not balanced across different `k`, you may want to use `schedule(dynamic, ...)` clause as well. Please refer to omp doc for more info.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5b5b6eb.aspx